Can I use “can” here?
I made up these sentences. Does using “can” in the sentences in bold sound natural to native English speakers?

This is one of the largest military airports in the country. The enemy is planning to launch another wave of attacks next month. If they take it, they can destroy our headquarters at the beginning of 2025.


I depends on the greater context. If the base is the headquarters then they have already destroyed HQ or prevented its use. If they occupy the airport and use it as an advance base for further attacks, they will be able to destroy the HQ: they can destroy it.

Is using can instead of will be able to acceptable here? @WeatherVane

Presumably the intent is already there. Consider a parent saying to child, "if you are ready, we can go to school". Not 'could', but "if you pass your exams, you could go to uni."

Sorry but I am talking about will be able to vs can not can vs could

'Can' sounds natural to me.

So can is better than will be able to here?

That's a matter of opinion: 'can' means 'able to', although I prefer 'can' – they probably will destroy the HQ. They are at war, not reviewing holiday options.

Questions about "is this okay" need to say more about why you think it might not be okay. An answer like "sure" isn't very helpful. Also: Comments aren't an official part of the question. Please use the "Edit" button under the question to add anything you needed to explain in the comments.

This question is similar to: How can I say "can" in the future form?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You're speaking hypothetically by saying "If they take it...". In this hypothetical context it is more common to use 'could', which indicates possibility. Using "can" suggests that the intent is already there - that they want to destroy the headquarters and this condition will allow them to proceed with that.

Is using “can” instead of “will be able to” acceptable here?

The "strongest" phrasing for consequences is If they take it, they will destroy our HQ.  It's really a matter of opinion, but imho in ascending order of strength / likelihood for the alternatives, the weakest is ...they could..., followed by ...they can, followed by ...they will be able to... That's to say I think they will be able to more strongly implies they will than the others. But that's mainly because will be able to is less likely, so I have to assume some reason for the "relatively uncommon"  choice. The obvious candidate reason is emphasis.

Modal can is often used with the meaning "there is nothing stopping it".
So this:

If they take it, they can destroy our headquarters at the beginning of 2025.

would have the practical meaning of "If they take it, there's nothing standing in the way of them destroying our headquarters at the beginning of 2025".
Presumably there are other unspoken constraints or limitations  or considerations that prevent them from doing so immediately, but by early 2025 there will be nothing to stop them from doing so.
P.S. It's also quite common (at least in American English) to find  present can in the main clause (rather than could) even when the subordinate clause is a condition, if the condition is expressed without a modal or other irrealis marking:

If they take it...

versus

If they should take it ...
If they were to take it ...
If they took it ...

